# google drive integration with service account in iOS for Swift

Tags: swift, google-api, google-drive-api, iso, service-accounts

I have successfully integrated the google drive sdk in my iOS project with swift language,
but the problem is I am getting the google drive data of the user when he logsIn instead of getting the data from the clients drive.
I have searched about it & the conclusion which I have get is using the service account, but there not much information about it ,
so how could I get this,
please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About Oauth**

Google Drive data is private user data.  In order to access private user data you need the users permission to access that data.

Normally we use Oauth.  The user is presented with a consent screen granting the application access to their data.  In the below example the Application "google analytics windows" Is requesting access to Google analytics from the user.

[image]

When this application runs it will then have access to the users Google analytics data.

**Your question**

> I have successfully integrated the google drive sdk in my iOS project with swift language, but the problem is I am getting the google drive data of the user when he logsIn instead of getting the data from the clients drive.

You appear to have authenticated your application and requested drive access of the user.  This will mean that you will be accessing the users data.   I am not sure what you mean by "Clients drive"  If you are referring to the client id and client secret of your application this is the project on Google developer console and it has no drive account a project on google developer console has no data.   Your application needs to be authenticated to something that will grant it data in this case you have used Oauth2 to grant it access to the users data.

**Service account**

Service accounts are used for server to server communication for when you the developer control a drive account that you want all of your users to be reading from.   Using service account authentication will mean that you are not accessing the users drive account but accessing the service accounts account.

I am not an IOS dev so cant help you with accessing drive with a service account.  After a bit of searching it appears that it may not be supported [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532051/1841839)

Comment: using a "client drive" I mean to say -  the Google drive of the account where I have created a client ID

Comment: The client id that you have created. Has no Access to any data by it self even that of the account that as used to created it. All a client id is is the name of an application that intends to use a Google api.  You may want to read http://www.daimto.com/google-development-beginners/