# Google API & Swift - The caller does not have permission

Tags: swift, google-sheets

I know others have asked but none of the solutions work for me. I'm creating a MacOS Desktop app that calls the Google Sheets API. I have the frameworks integrated, can log into a session and get permissions to access GDrive, GMail and Sheets.

[image]

To make the Sheets API call I was following along with this [example code:](https://github.com/mipar52/google-examples-swift/blob/master/google-examples-swift/Controllers/SpredsheetsController.swift)

Here's my function that makes the call:

```
func readSpreadsheet(_ dictData:Dictionary<String, Any>, completion: @escaping returnStringClosure) {
    
    sheetService.apiKey = strAPIKey
    
    if var spreadsheetId = dictData["id"] as? String {
        
        //temp id - I own this spreadsheet so it should work
        spreadsheetId = "1NjxNyZqR5THZXeVZkTZpCnEFZR-SwCgZUzJ6qkb-qhQ"
        let range = "A1:Z"
        let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet
            .query(withSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range:range)
        
        sheetService.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error executing the read sheet query: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion("Failed to read data:\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let result = result as? GTLRSheets_ValueRange else {
                print("No results were returned for the spreadsheer request.")
                completion("No results were returned for the spreadsheer request.")
                return
            }
                
            let rows = result.values!
            var stringRows = rows as! [[String]]
                
            for row in stringRows {
                stringRows.append(row)
                print(row)
            }
                
            if rows.isEmpty {
                print("No data found.")
                return
            }
                
            completion("Success!")
            print("Number of rows in sheet: \(rows.count)")
        }
    }
     
}
```

The error happens on the  sheetService.executeQuery(query) function. I get this error message:

```
There was an error executing the read sheet query: The caller does not have permission
```

But I am logged in to Google, give the app access to Sheets. The sheet in question is restricted to my company's domain. But I am also the creator of that sheet, so my access is editor. If I change the access to `anyone with the link` I can read the file but this is proprietary stuff so it can't be public.

I do have a service account, not 100% sure on how to use that yet, but on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925086/google-drive-integration-with-service-account-in-ios-for-swift) it seems that would not be what I need anyway:

> Service accounts are used for server to server communication for when you the developer control a drive account that you want all of your users to be reading from. Using service account authentication will mean that you are not accessing the users drive account but accessing the service accounts account.

I need people to log in and access their own accounts.

Comment: What are the OAuth [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) that you defined?

Comment: The three I mentioned, gmail, gdrive, sheets, read only for all.

Comment: Since the error happens in executeQuery(), based on this documentation in requires this [scope](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-statement#executequerysql). Try to add that scope and test.

Comment: Based on what documentation? There was no link, could you drop one for the docs?

Comment: Here's the documentation for executeQuery() - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-statement#executequerysql

Comment: Oh thanks, I was on that page, thought there might have been another.